# jquery hide and show method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Note : I use `codeigniter` framework

EDIT : I dont know its related or not, but the element that i want to shown (`form_range_kelas`) is a `p`

I have a `dropdown` that will control other html element's visibility. I only have a little experience with `jquery/javascript` so i search on this site and i got this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ct5r/)

So, i followed that fiddle, but its not working..its just not working, i tried to see firebug but it seems like nothing happened.

This is the `dropdown` code (**Using** `codeigniter's` **library**):

```
        <p>
            Search By : <?php echo form_dropdown('ddl_search', $data_search, 'id="ddl_search"');?>
        </p>
```

This is my script(from **jquery ui**, **its included jquery right?**):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>
```

This is my `html` element which i want to change it's visibility :

```
 <p id="form_range_kelas">
            Kelas :
            <?php echo form_dropdown('ddl_kelas1', $list_kelas, 'id="ddl_kelas1"');?> -
            <?php echo form_dropdown('ddl_kelas2', $list_kelas, 'id="ddl_kelas2"');?>
        </p>
```

This is my **FULL** `javascript/jquery` code (**NOTE : The alert is NOT working**):

```
 <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });

    $('#ddl_search').change(function() {
        alert("a");
        if ($(this).val() == 'range_kelas')
            $('#form_range_kelas').show();
        else
            $('#form_range_kelas').hide();
    });
 </script>
```

And this is the data in my `controller`(**codeigniter**) :

```
$data['data_search'] = array('kelas' => 'Kelas',
                         'range_kelas' => 'Range Kelas', 
                         'nama' => 'Nama',
                         'alamat' => 'Alamat',
                         'bulan' => 'Bulan Lahir',
                         'range_bulan' => 'Range Bulan Lahir');
```

What should i do?

Thanks :D

Comment: Whats not working is it not showing the text box?

Comment: Your JS Fiddle works perfect

Comment: Can you send us the link to the page you are working on?

Comment: Does `$('#ddl_search')` yield any matches at the time the event is registered? Does `.change` ever fire?

Comment: Same here, working JS Fiddle..

Comment: @LmC Yes, my div is not shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using this code to create the ddl_search dropdown?

```
form_dropdown('ddl_search', $data_search, '', 'id="ddl_search"');
```

Please note that your id="ddl_search" should be the 4th parameter and not 3rd parameter. Then only your dropdown ddl_search will be craeted with correct ID and the code you have written will work.

Also write the change function inside "$(function() {}"

```
 $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

       $('#ddl_search').change(function() {
        alert("a");
        if ($(this).val() == 'range_kelas')
            $('#form_range_kelas').show();
        else
            $('#form_range_kelas').hide();
       });
   });
```

---

**Alternate Solution**

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('ddl_search', $data_search, '', 'id="ddl_search" onchange="myfunc();"');?>
```

And use the code in a js function

```
function myfunc() {         
        alert('here');
        if ($('#ddl_search').val() == 'range_kelas')
            $('#form_range_kelas').show();
        else
            $('#form_range_kelas').hide();    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :D
Yes, i relized i made a mistake here. But the code is still not working. Even the aler("a"); not shown

Comment: does it shows any error? have you checked in firebug? have you checked now it shows the drop down with its correct id?

Comment: No error is shown, yes the id is correct. I really dont know whats going on here, have been stuck for hours

Comment: check my edited comment.

Comment: have you moved the .change function inside function as i have shown in my answer?

Comment: Please check my alternate solution in the answer above.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, your second solution works to me. Its too bad i only can upvote 1 time. Can you kindly give me an explanation of what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('#ddl_search').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'range_kelas'){
      $('#form_range_kelas').show();
  }
  else{
      $('#form_range_kelas').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. No, i tried this one for the 1st time, its not working

Comment: try to alert the selected dropdown value(alert($(this).val());) and check whether the value 'range_kelas' is getting..

Comment: No, its not working. Please see my updated question, in the script section. Thanks

Comment: are you sure about the 3rd parameter 'id="ddl_search" and 1st parameter 'ddl_search' may not get conflicted in this code <?php echo form_dropdown('ddl_search', $data_search, 'id="ddl_search"');?>

Comment: Yes, i made a mistake in the parameter too. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, I wrote and tested the script and it works.
In your select, you add an onchange value:

```
<select onchange="selectfunction()" id="formselect">
    <option value="range_kelas">yes</option>
    <option value="othervalue">no</option>
</select>
```

At the top of your document you add this script and change it accordingly

```
<script>
    function selectfunction(){
        var e = document.getElementById("formselect");
        var selectedindex = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        if(selectedindex == "range_kelas"){
            document.getElementById('FORM_YOU_WANT_TO_HIDE').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
        }
    }
</script>
```

It's not completely finished, but you get the gist.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i prefer the jquery way :D